# Binary Tree traversal with non-static methods?

Tags: python, binary-tree

I was coding a BinTree class looking like that:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, key, left=None, right=None):
        self.key = key
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    @staticmethod
    def traversal(t):
        if t is None:
            #  Do something
            pass
        else:
            #  Preorder
            Tree.traversal(t.left)
            #  Inorder
            Tree.traversal(t.right)
            #  Postorder
```

And I was curious about doing it with a non-static method. I tried to do this which seems not to work:

```
def traversal(self):
    if self is None:
        #  Do something
        pass
    else:
        #  Preorder
        self.left.traversal()
        #  Inorder
        self.left.traversal()
        #  Postorder
```

Is it because `self` can not be `None`?

Anyway, I would like to know it this is possible to do a BinTree traversal (and even other methods, like insertion, etc.) with a non-static method either recursive or iterative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's true that `self` cannot be `None` in a normal method call.<sup>1</sup> If it's `None`, you'll get an error trying to call the method on it.<sup>2</sup>

But that just means you have to reorganize things a bit: Instead of unconditionally calling `traversal` on your subtrees, counting on the fact that it will safely do nothing if they're `None`, you have to check whether they're `None` first so you can skip the call.

Since `Tree` instances are always truthy (since you haven't defined a `__bool__` or `__len__` on the type to override that default), you can check it this way:

```
if self.left:
```

So:

```
def traversal(self):
    #  Preorder
    if self.left: self.left.traversal()
    #  Inorder
    if self.right: self.right.traversal()
    #  Postorder
```

---

You can similarly make every tree method into a normal method—but you will similarly have to make small changes to some of them.

---

<sub>1. Well, except the methods defined on `NoneType`. Obviously when you `print(None)`, inside the `NoneType.__str__` method, `self` is `None`…</sub>

<sub>2. Well, this isn't quite true. If you try to call `self.left.traversal()` when `self.left` is `None`, you're calling `NoneType.traversal`, and there is no such method, so that's an `AttributeError`. But if you try to call `Tree.traversal(self.left)`, on the other hand, you're trying to call an unbound `Tree` method with `None`, which is a `TypeError`—but it's one that Python 3.x (unlike 2.x) implementations are not required to check. And no version of CPython or PyPy 3.x so far has checked, and they probably never will. So, it actually *would* work if you wrote it that way. But that's obviously not something you should rely on.</sub>

Comment: Yeah sorry, the call was just a copy mistake, I've wrote self.left.traversal(). Thanks for your answer ;)

Comment: you forgot to change `Tree.traversal(self.right)` in your last code block

Comment: @Lap The funny thing is, if you actually _had_ made that error, it would have masked your other error (assuming you're using Python 3.x).